# How to plot a graph over map of a country?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The code I tried is,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':phi_pp, 'y':lambda_pp})
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='line',legend=None)
plt.xlabel('IPP Longitude')
ax=plt.ylabel('IPP Latitude')

im = plt.imread("Map_of_India.jpg")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
```

The sample df is:

```
         x          y
0   15.121270   4246.948356
1   12.103705   4248.927074
2   8.583936    4247.596317
3   18.173364   4244.749973
4   14.175727   4290.142397
```

The two plots are not plotting on same axes.
Any image of Indian map can be used as a sample image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first plot the image using `imshow`. Then make a second axes at the same position as the image axes and set its background transparent. Now you can plot your dataframe on this new axes and it will overlay the image.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/coronavirus-tracking/images/maps/IND/hotspots.png')

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [15.12127, 12.103705, 8.583936, 18.173364, 14.175727],
                   'y': [4246.948356, 4248.927074, 4247.596317, 4244.749973, 4290.142397]})

fig, ax_im = plt.subplots()
ax_im.imshow(im)
ax_im.set_axis_off()

ax_df = fig.add_axes(ax_im.get_position())
ax_df.patch.set_alpha(0)
df.plot('x', 'y', legend=None, xlabel='IPP Longitude', ylabel='IPP Latitude', ax=ax_df)
```

[image]

Comment: getting an error ```'Line2D' object has no property 'xlabel'```

Comment: maybe you should update your pandas, tested with version 1.4.2

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: `pip install -U pandas`, or you can set the labels as you did like `ax_df.set_xlabel('IPP Longitude')`, same for y label

Comment: Is it possible to move the map such that a specific (lat, lon) point is positioned at some given point on the plot? Let's say a specific city of that country is exactly on top of a given point in the plot?

Comment: Here is the post to my question in case you guys can give me a road map. Thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232228/put-a-country-map-onto-a-scatter-plot-using-python-3

Comment: @Ash no, the map is just an image like any other image. If you can't use [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) this only way is to crop the image of the map as needed and adjust the axes coords accordingly.